# Angular Tabs Component Using Bootstrap 5 - Why do the tabs shift when there are more than 8 characters in the tab title?

Tags: css, angular, sass, tabs, bootstrap-5

Angular 14
Bootstrap 5

I made this reusable tabs component with pipes in between the tabs, and it works great. But whenever there are more than 8 characters in a tab title, when I click through the tabs, the tabs shift just the slightest bit and I can't figure out why.

Here is the [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-heutcz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

You'll see there is a tabs and a tab component, and the main app component that uses the tabs and tab component. Pretty straightforward, I just can't figure out what is causing the slight shift. I was thinking it has something to do with the hidden first pipe achieved by using -1 margin. But even when I comment that out in the css, it still shifts.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Not sure anymore if it has to do with the number of character in the tab titles.

EDIT 2: Pretty sure it has to do with the width of .nav-item. When I add a static width to it, like 200px for example, the slight shifting goes away. I can't have a static width though, because tab titles won't be centered, might be too much space for short tab titles, not enough space for long tab titles, etc..

EDIT 3: It's the font-weight in the active state of the nav-link that is causing the issue (it changes from 400 to 500) but I'm not sure how to keep the same box size when the font size changes. `box-sizing: border-box` does not work. Here is the css:

```
.nav-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 8px;
  height: 33px;
  color: #4285eb !important;
}

.nav-link.active {
  background: rgba(66, 133, 235, 0.15) !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subbing out

`font-weight: 500`

with

`text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgb(141, 127, 127);`

and it looks pretty much the same without the tabs shifting. Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future. If anyone knows *why* this is, please share!